# Kubectl run set nodeSelector

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to specify the nodeSelector when using the Kubernetes run command?

I don't have a yaml file and I only want to override the nodeSelector.

I tried the following but didn't work:

```
kubectl run myservice --image myserviceimage:latest --overrides='{ "nodeSelector": { "beta.kubernetes.io/os": "windows" } }'
```

Comment: tl:tr add this flag to your kubectl run: --overrides='{ "apiVersion": "v1", "spec": { "template": { "spec": { "nodeSelector": { "kubernetes.io/hostname": "NODE_HOSTANME" } } } } }'

Answer (score 26):

`nodeSelector` must be wrapped with a `spec`. Like so

```
kubectl run -ti --rm test --image=ubuntu:18.04 --overrides='{"spec": { "nodeSelector": {"kubernetes.io/hostname": "eks-prod-4"}}}'
```

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

`kubectl run myservice --image myserviceimage:latest --overrides='{"apiVersion": "v1", "spec": {"nodeSelector": { "beta.kubernetes.io/os": "windows" }}}'`

Answer (score 10):

I have an actual answer now... **Here is my final answer**:

In order to specify the node selector via the run command (and make it work so that it runs on a certain node), we can do the following:

1. Make sure that the node that you want to target can schedule pods on it. My master node (master-0) was unprepared for this, so I had to remove its taint, via the command:

   ```sh
   kubectl taint node master-0 node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule-
   ```

   (The trailing - is important), and where master-0 is replaced by the name of yours, if this case is needed.
2. Add the override command to the kubectl run command.

   ```sh
   kubectl run hello-world --replicas=1 --labels="run=load-balancer-example" --image=gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0  --port=8080 --overrides='{ "apiVersion": "v1", "spec": { "template": { "spec": { "nodeSelector": { "kubernetes.io/hostname": "master-0" } } } } }'
   ```

   Make sure to use proper `apiVersion` based on your kubernetes version. You might need to use `apps/v1beta1` instead of `v1`. You can run this to get proper version on your installation:

   ```sh
   kubectl api-versions
   ```

   check this thread if you faced any issues with the `apiVersion`: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/55894

I am not sure how the above answers work, as they do not have enough encapsulation in the json... nor how: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/45153 works, as to me the problem was that:

The key I was missing was that: it's not `.spec.nodeSelector`, it has to be `.spec.template.spec.nodeSelector`

Comment: I found that if I removed the `"apiVersion": "apps/v1beta1",` then it works fine like that too.

Comment: "apiVersion": "v1"

Answer (score 5):

In Kubernetes 1.12 and newer, the matching rules have changed to use nodeAffinity.

```sh
kubectl run hello-world --replicas=1 --labels="run=load-balancer-example" --image=gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0  --port=8080 --overrides='{"apiVersion":"v1","spec":{"affinity":{"nodeAffinity":{"requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution":{"nodeSelectorTerms":[{"matchFields":[{"key":"metadata.name","operator":"In","values":["my-chosen-node-01"]}]}]}}}}}'
```

Note that this approach works fine in Unix like shells but there are quoting issues with running this under PowerShell on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

The [`kubectl run` documentation](https://kubernetes-v1-4.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_run/) mentions:

```
--overrides="":
```

> An inline JSON override for the generated object.
>   If this is non-empty, it is used to override the generated object.
>   **Requires that the object supply a [valid apiVersion field](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/#api-groups)**.

So at least try:

```
--overrides='{ "apiVersion": "v1", "nodeSelector"... }'
```

If that does not work, check the yaml actually generated (from [issue 24873](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24873#issuecomment-337407741));

```
for n in $(kubectl get -o=name pvc,configmap,serviceaccount,secret,ingress,service,deployment,statefulset,hpa,job,cronjob)
do
    mkdir -p $(dirname $n)
    kubectl get -o=yaml --export $n > $n.yaml
done
```

Comment: I am looking for a way to only provide the nodeSelector without having to provide the full yaml. Is the above going to override the generated yaml or only the nodeSelector? (I think it overrides the whole thing)

Comment: @nbilal I didn't test it directly, but it should override the common values.

Comment: I doubt a bit that this will work because the full json path is not provided. nodeSelector is under "spec".

Comment: @nbilal in that case, that would be `spec.nodeSelector ...`