# kubectl run override nodeselctor: error: Invalid JSON Patch

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm trying to override the node selector for a `kubectl run`.

```
kubectl run -it powershell --image=mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:lts-nanoserver-1809-20211215 --restart=Never --overrides='{ "apiVersion": "v1", "spec": { "template": { "spec": { "nodeSelector": { "kubernetes.io/os": "windows" } } } } }' -- pwsh
```

But I get "Invalid Json Path".

This is my yaml if I do a deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 ...
spec:
  ...
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      ...
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: windows
```

and if I do `get pods -o json` I get:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Pod",
    "metadata": {
        ...
    },
    "spec": {
        ...
        "nodeSelector": {
            "kubernetes.io/os": "windows"
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubectl run set nodeSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51161647/kubectl-run-set-nodeselector)

Comment: Thanks @VasiliAngapov! I still does not understand why my template does not work. What is wrong with my Json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kubectl run` is a command to start a `Pod`. You can read more about it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands)

```
kubectl run -it powershell --image=mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:lts-nanoserver-1809-20211215 --restart=Never --overrides='{ "apiVersion": "v1", "spec": { "template": { "spec": { "nodeSelector": { "kubernetes.io/os": "windows" } } } } }' -- pwsh
```

Using a command above you are trying run a `Pod` with specification `"template": { "spec": {`  which is used only for `Deployment` and that is why you get an error `Invalid Json Path`.

`nodeSelector` as you can see in [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) could be specify under `spec` in `Pod`config file as below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    env: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  nodeSelector:
    disktype: ssd
```

When you add `--dry-run=client -o yaml`to your command to see how the object would be processed, you will see below output which doesn't have `nodeSelector`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: powershell
  name: powershell
spec:
  containers:
  - image: mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:lts-nanoserver-1809-20211215
    name: powershell
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Never
status: {}
```

To solve your issue, you can delete `template` and `spec` from you command which should look as below:

```
kubectl run -it powershell --image=mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:lts-nanoserver-1809-20211215 --restart=Never --overrides='{ "apiVersion": "v1", "spec": { "nodeSelector": { "kubernetes.io/os": "windows" } } }' -- pwsh
```

Adding `--dry-run=client -o yaml`to see what will be changed, you will see that `nodeSelector` exist:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: powershell
  name: powershell
spec:
  containers:
  - image: mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:lts-nanoserver-1809-20211215
    name: powershell
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: windows
  restartPolicy: Never
status: {}
```

Comment: I have tried your command but still getting 'Invalid JSON Path'

kubectl run -it powershell --image=mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:lts-nanoserver-1809-20211215 --restart=Never --overrides='{ "apiVersion": "v1",
"spec": { "nodeSelector": { "kubernetes.io/os": "windows" } } }' -- pwsh