# Kubernetes Run CURL on Node with Taints

Tags: kubernetes, curl, azure-aks

Currently I run a curl container and directly connect with its terminal to verify connectivity to services and check we can can connect on some port to an external service or a service maintained by some other team.

```
kubectl run curl -it --rm --image=curlimages/curl -- sh
```

Now the problem is that I have to run a curl container on a Node that has taints and tolerations enabled. Is there a way to run this container on by providing tolerations from the kubectl cli?

For reference I am using AKS service and we use helm for deployment. In order to schedule workloads on the tainted nodes we use a combination of telerations and nodeaffinity in combination. Configs given below.

```
  spec:
      tolerations:
        - key: "mendix"
          operator: "Equal"
          value: "true"
          effect: "NoSchedule"
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: appType
                operator: In
                values:
                - mendix
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubectl run set nodeSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51161647/kubectl-run-set-nodeselector)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, nodeSelector on its own would not work for tainted node.

Comment: @Adiii it wouldn't work. I have already tried that also in the answer you shared the person has already mentioned that the TAINT was removed before using NodeSelector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, if you need to run it on a specific node that is tainted (it will run despite any taints):

```
kubectl run curl -it --rm --image=curlimages/curl --overrides \
  '{"spec":{"tolerations":[{"operator":"Exists"}]},"nodeName":"mynode"}' \
  -- sh
```

Comment: I have tried that too as well. For reference I'm using tolerations and node affinity in combination to schedule workload on that specific node. I have updated the question and added the details there.

Comment: @Faisal, I am quite surprised that the command above does not work. What error do you receive? Can you do `kubectl get ev` ?

Comment: It just times out and when I check the logs on the cluster it says didn't tolerate the taints, also the JSON in the command you provided was not valid had to fix it.

Comment: I don't get this. I've tainted a node, and verified:
`Taints: mendix=true:NoSchedule`
Ran the command and it works. The json is also correct, there should have been no need to fix it.

Comment: Maybe a shell problem? Running on win maybe?

Comment: Yeah it works sorry I checked and made a typo in the command yesterday.